# Need to change output voltage on MIC5891 driver

Tags: voltage, led, control, driver, output

I have an LED control panel that uses the [MIC5891](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/20005638A.pdf) driver. I measured the VBB load voltage at 9.05 V, however, the outputs (1 through 8) all register at 1.96 V. What could be controlling this output voltage? What changes can I make to the inputs to increase the output voltage to 3.0 V?

Comment: Welcome! Schematic please.

Comment: Did you connect the LEDs without current limit resistor in series?